# jquery slide down notification on form submit-nt working?? Duration taken from user(form)!

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

Can someone please throw light on how to produce notification or alerts on form submit? The notification should stay on users page for time given by user in form. Submit button will take duration from the form and produce a jquery notification/alert for that duration. My code is not producing intended results

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                time: "required",           
            },
            messages: {
                time: "Please enter Time in Miliseconds",                  
            }
        });

        $("#notify").hide();

        $("#form").submit(function(e) {
            $("#notify").slideDown();

            var timeOut = parseInt($("#time").val()) || 100; // default timeout

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#notify").slideUp();
            }, timeOut);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

```css
#notify
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FF0000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}


#message
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#form .formelement
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 900px;
}

#form .formelement label{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 110px;
}

#form .submit {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
}

#form .formelement label.error {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 0 10px 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="notify">
    <div id="message">SUCCESSFULL</div>
</div>

<fieldset>



<form action="" id="form" >

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="time">Time (in MiliSec): </label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time"/>
            </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="Show Success" class="submit" id="subm"/>
            </div>



</form> 
</fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot closing the document ready in the snippet

Comment: @AndreasFurster i have updated it..plz hav a luk..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="notification">
    Notification content
</div>    

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                time: "required",           
            },
            messages: {
                time: "Please enter Time in Miliseconds",                  
            }
        });

        $("#notification").hide();

        $("#form").submit(function(e) {
            $("#notification").slideDown();

            var timeOut = $("#time").val() || 100; // default timeout

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#notification").slideUp();
            }, timeOut);

            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried it!! but not working..maybe becoz of some code error frm my side..plzz check

Comment: You have a double `.submit`. Delete the first

Comment: don't see any changes? You have a .submit, in that submit you have jQuery ready, in there you have a .submit again

Comment: Still not working ..submit button not responding ..not even with messages(Please enter time in Ms)

Comment: try parsing the value to an int: `var timeOut = parseInt($("#time").val())`